# Suspension of application from Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play

Yesterday I put up my Android app on the Google play store. Today the app was removed from it without proper reason. Reason for suspension of app

REASON FOR REMOVAL: Violation of the intellectual property and impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy. Please refer to the IP infringement and impersonation policy help article for more information.

Your app and/or elements of its listing on Google Play, including title, description, logo(s), or promotional screen-shots must not include unauthorized usage of protected works belonging to a third party.

Your app icon and promotional screen-shots must not contain images that appear confusingly similar to existing products.

My app name: Finger Scan Locker

icon and screen shots are desgined by our desginer.

icon

[image]

screenshots

[image: screenshots]

[image: screenshots]

I don't copy the icon and screen shots,that are developed by my designer. 
This is my second app got suspended from Google play store with same reason. 
so,can any one give me solution am i missing anything?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your question is completely off-topic here. We do not deal with legal issues on SO. This is for development related stuff.

Comment: You have an iphone in your app icon!, that might be it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play policies and intellectual property.

Comment: Try submitting an appeal for your app removal/suspension from Google Play using the form in the link below:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/appappeals

Answer (score 2):

As a comment says it might be your icon that is detected as an Apple IP infrigment because it is an iphone. Ask your designer how he did it.

Comment: but it does not have watermark.it just like iphone model